# Flex css layout with fixed and variable elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I am hoping to create the following layout in pure CSS. I know that I can achieve this with a JavaScript solution, but a CSS solution would be much cleaner, if it is possible.

[image: desired result]

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8j60drc/) which I know is incorrect, to provide a starting point. The HTML and CSS I use in the jsFiddle are shown below.

Notes:

- I would like this to fill the full height of the window, so that there is no scroll bar for the page (but see my last point)
- There are two sections that can contain a variable number of elements.
- The red elements are images which the user can add on the fly, and which will be given a frame with a fixed aspect ratio (shown here as a square)
- The green section will contain a list which will have at least one item, so it will have a fixed minimum height. It may have up to four items, so its height may change. I would prefer not to have this section scroll. If the user makes the window too short for both the green and the blue elements to show full height, then the page as a whole will have to scroll.

My question is: can this be done in pure CSS? If you know that there is a solution, and if you can provide some pointers as to how I can achieve it, then I can continue to work towards that solution. If you know that there is no solution, then I will simply adopt a JavaScript approach.

If there is a solution, and you would be happy to share it, then I will be delighted that you have saved me a lot of time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flex</title>
    <style>
body, html {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
background: #000;
}
main {
width: 30em;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #333;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
}
.head{
width:100%;
-webkit-flex: 3em;
        flex: 3em;
background: #fcc;
}
.expand{
width:100%;
overflow:auto;
}
.filler {
width:100%;
height:20em;
background: #003;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.space {
width:100%;
height:10em;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.foot{
width:100%;
-webkit-flex: 0 0 2em;
        flex: 0 0 2em;
background: #cfc;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<main>
  <div class="head">HEAD</div>
  <div class="expand">
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="space"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="foot">FOOT</div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it well,

```css
main {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.head {
    min-height: 3em;
}
.foot {
    min-height: 2em;
}
.expand {
    flex-basis: 0; /* Initial height */
    flex-grow: 1; /* Grow as much as possible */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}
main {
  width: 20em;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #333;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.head {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 3em;
  background: #fcc;
}
.expand {
  width: 100%;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
.filler {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20em;
  background: #003;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.space {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.foot {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2em;
  background: #cfc;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="head">HEAD</div>
  <div class="expand">
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="space"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="foot">FOOT</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks, this certainly takes care of the vertical arrangement. However, it does not ensure that the red elements maintain their aspect ratio as the window is resized, or the scroll bar is auto-toggled. I'm thinking that I need to enclose each in its own div which fills the (available) width of main...

Comment: @JamesNewton The scrollbar is auto toggled because of `overflow: auto`. And if `.expand` contains images, those have an intrinsic aspect ratio. Just use `height: auto` on the images, and their height will be calculated according to their width and aspect ratio.